# MonoDevelop without code completion for Unity function parameters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, code-completion

code completion issues seem to be an ongoing issue with Mono Develop, and now I have a new twist of it where the past solutions don't work: thought code completion works in general, it does no longer for function parameters. So for `foo(obj bar){...}` it won't offer `bar` in the completion popup within the function scope. However as soon as I typed `bar`, the contained members will be shown again. So it's just the function parameters that don't make it into the local function scope resolution.

So what is the next quick hack to resolve this one ;-)

It's Mono Develop 4.0.1 as part of Unity patch 4.6.1p5.

Thanks, habitoti

Comment: you may want to try Xamarin Studio

Comment: I think given the price of a Unity license it is not asked for too much to get a properly working editor included. Xamarin would be an additional fee...